# java regex parsing error

Tags: java, regex

i would like to use this regex in java

```
^class QuineHash.*?{(.*?(\s))*}$
```

However when i launch the function it throws an illegal repetion error.

These are the commands:

```
String pattern = "^class QuineHash.*?{(.*?(\\s))*}$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 18
^class QuineHash.*?{(.*?(\s))*}$
```

How can i solve the problem?

EDIT:

I solve the problem simply by changing the previous regex with this one:

```
class QuineHash(?:.*?\\s)*}
```

Comment: Please explain your regex.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `?` at the end of the sub-expression `^class QuineHash.*?` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = "^class QuineHash.*?\{(.*?(\\s))*\}$";
```

Escape the braces!

Comment: I'm not sure that the regular expression you are using will yield the desired result. You might explain what you intend to parse with this regular expression.